# How can I use a single form for editing comments and replies in this Laravel 8 app?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have made a blogging application in Laravel 8.

The articles support comments and comment replies. I am currently working on the *edit/update comments* functionality.

In the Comment model, I "merge" comments and replies like so:

```
public function replies() {
  return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

In the controller, I have the below method for getting the comments with replies:

```
private function get_commentQuery(int $article_id, int $limit = 0, int $offset = 0): object
{
  $commentQuery = Comment::where(['article_id' => $article_id, 'approved' => 1])
    ->orderBy('id', $this->comments_orderby_direction)
    ->with('replies', function ($query) {
      $query->where('approved', 1);
    });

  if ($offset > 0) {
    $commentQuery = $commentQuery->offset($offset);
  }
  if ($limit > 0) {
    $commentQuery = $commentQuery->limit($limit);
  }

  return $commentQuery;
}
```

In `comments-list.blade.php` I have:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    @if (null == $comment->parent_id)
        <li class="depth-1 comment">
            <div class="comment__avatar">
                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $comment->user->avatar) }}"
                    alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}" width="50" height="50">
            </div>
            <div class="comment__content">
                <div class="comment__info">
                  <div class="comment__author">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
                  <div class="comment__meta">
                      <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</div>
                      @auth
                        <div class="comment__reply">
                          @if ($comment->user->id !== Auth::user()->id)
                              <a class="comment-reply-link" href="#0">
                                <i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Reply
                            </a> 
                          @endif
                            
                          @if ($comment->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                              <a href="#0" class="comment-edit-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                              </a>
                              @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-delete-form')
                          @endif
                        </div>
                      @endauth
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="comment__text">
                  <p>{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            @auth
              @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')

              @if ($comment->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form')
              @endif
            @endauth

            {{-- Comment replies --}}
            @if (count($comment->replies))
                <ul class="children">
                    @foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
                        <li class="depth-2 comment">
                            <div class="comment__avatar">
                                <img class="avatar" src="{{ asset('images/avatars/' . $reply->user->avatar) }}"
                                    alt="{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}"
                                    width="50" height="50">
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment__content">
                                <div class="comment__info">
                                    <div class="comment__author">{{ $reply->user->first_name }}
                                        {{ $reply->user->last_name }}</div>
                                    <div class="comment__meta">
                                        <div class="comment__time">{{ date('jS M Y', strtotime($reply->created_at)) }}
                                        </div>
                                        @auth
                                            <div class="comment__reply">
                                              @if ($reply->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                                                <a href="#0" class="comment-edit-link">
                                                  <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit
                                                </a>
                                                @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-delete-form')
                                              @endif
                                            </div>
                                        @endauth
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comment__text">
                                    <p>{{ $reply->body }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            @auth
                              @if ($reply->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
                                @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form')
                              @endif
                            @endauth
                        </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

My intention is to use one form template for editing both *comments* and replies. I have added the form for editing comments in a partial called `comment-edit-form.blade.php`:

```
<form class="commentEditForm" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.update', !isset($reply) ? $comment->id : $reply->id) }}" autocomplete="off" novalidate> 
    @csrf
      <fieldset>
        <div class="message form-field">
          <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required>{{ !isset($reply) ? $comment->body : $reply->body }}</textarea>

          @error('msg')
          <p class="help-block text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
          @enderror
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Update Comment" type="submit">
      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

As is visible above, I have tried to differentiate comments from replies because, of course, they have different ids and bodies.

#### The problem

For a reason I was unable to figure out, all comments that come after a comment reply in the foreach loop, are prepopulated with the reply's body.

[image]

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is a reliable fix for this issue?

Comment: could you maybe add a better picture/example, is ioana popa comment body=null? also what is the role of ```@include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-form')```. what were you expecting in the red outlined comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

The `$reply` variable's scope within the `@include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form')` call is causing the problem. It persists between iterations, leading to incorrect pre-population of subsequent comment forms.

**Solution:**

***Pass the relevant comment or reply object to the partial expicitly:***

```
@if ($comment->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
  @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form', ['commentOrReply' => $comment])
@endif

@foreach ($comment->replies as $reply)
  @if ($reply->user->id == Auth::user()->id)
    @include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form', ['commentOrReply' => $reply])
  @endif
@endforeach
```

***Access the passed object using `$commentOrReply` and adjust conditions:***

```
<form class="commentEditForm" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.update', $commentOrReply->id) }}" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    @csrf
    <fieldset>
        <div class="message form-field">
            <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required>{{ $commentOrReply->body }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Where inside `comments-list.blade.php` should I add the code? Can you add your code in the context of mine? Thanks!

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, in the only two places you include the /partials/comment-edit-form, just modify by replacing: ```@include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form')``` with ```@include('themes/' . $theme_directory . '/partials/comment-edit-form', ['commentOrReply' => $reply ( in the second) $comment (in the first])```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from variable scope within your Blade template. When you include the `comment-edit-form.blade.php` partial within the loop that iterates over comments and replies, the `$reply` from the previous iteration is still accessible in the scope of the next iteration. As a result, even when processing a primary comment (not a reply), the `$reply` variable is set and the form gets populated with the reply's body. To resolve this, you need to ensure that the `$reply`  is not mistakenly used for primary comments. One way to do this is by explicitly passing the relevant comment or reply to the partial.

Comment: How would you do that?